# GO言語での並列計算の仕組みについて (パート２)

Tags: go

以前に[GO言語での並列計算の仕組みについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36946/go%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%A6%E5%88%97%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%95%E7%B5%84%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)について質問をさせていただきました。
今回はそれをもう少し発展させたいのですが、スタックしてしまい、また皆様のお知恵を拝借したく、ここで質問させていただいています。

まずtoy scriptを示した後に、質問させていただきます。

```
package main

import (
      "fmt"
      "math/rand"
      "time"
      "sync"
      "runtime"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func Sleep() {
    defer wg.Done()

    r := rand.Intn(3);
    if r == 0 {
      time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond) //0.01秒停止
    } else if r == 1 {
      time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)  //0.1秒停止
    } else if r == 2 {
      time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond) //3秒停止
    }
}

func main() {
  N := 8;
  runtime.GOMAXPROCS(N)

  idx := 0;
  for i:=0; i<18; i++ {
    fmt.Println("process:", i)
    wg.Add(1)
    idx += 1;
    go Sleep();
    if idx%N == 0 {
        wg.Wait();
    }
  }

  wg.Wait();
}
```

このscriptでは、goroutineを用いまして、Sleep functionを動かしています。

このfunctionでは、ランダムの数字により、Sleepの時間を変えるようにしています。
８個並列して計算させますと、そのうちの一個以上で「3秒停止」になるように設定しています。
この場合、「wg.Wait()」があるため、他の計算が終了していても、8つ中一つでも「3秒停止」があれば、その回では「3秒間停止」する必要が出てきてしまいます。

質問ですが、goroutineでは、終わったものから次の計算をさせるような機能はあるのでしょうか？

具体的には、以下のようなことを想定しております。
8つ中1つだけ「3秒停止」であり、他７つは「0.1秒停止」の場合、
0.1秒停止が終わった7つのプロセスだけ進むようなことは可能でしょうか？
ただし、最大８プロセスだけ動かすことを仮定しております。
（実際には、それ以上動かしますと、プロセス間で干渉が起こり、計算時間が長くなってしまいますので。）

ご教授、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 過去の質問についた回答を承認されては…

Comment: hlbさん、大変申し訳ありません。自分は、こちらのsiteの使い方が、まだ十分に理解していないようです。いつもは「役に立つ」という三角形のマークをクリックしているだけですが、どうやらそれだけでは不十分のようですね。「回答を承認」はどのようにしたらよいかを教えていただけると、今後も役に立つと思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

各 goroutine 間に依存関係が無く、ただ並列に動いている goroutine の最大数を 8 にしたいだけなのであれば、ワーカースレッドの形にすると分かりやすいのではないかと思いました。

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func Sleep(id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, req chan int) {
    log.Printf("ID %d: invoked!\n", id)
    defer log.Printf("ID %d: finished!\n", id)
    defer wg.Done()

    for {
        r, ok := <-req
        if !ok {
            return
        }

        log.Printf("ID %d: waiting... (r = %d)", id, r)
        if r == 0 {
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond) //0.01秒停止
        } else if r == 1 {
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond) //0.1秒停止
        } else if r == 2 {
            time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond) //3秒停止
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    N := 8
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(N)
    req := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // ワーカーを N 個作る
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go Sleep(i, &wg, req)
    }

    // 仕事を作る
    for i := 0; i < 18; i++ {
        req <- rand.Intn(3)
    }
    close(req)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wkxeiFoLZn))

チャネルを close すると `ok` が `false` になることや、チャネルの送受信まわりでブロッキングが起こっていることに注意してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの不勉強で、goroutineでワーカーを作ることの理解が足りませんでした。確かに、ワーカーを必要分だけ作成し、それに随時値を投げ入れるように作成すれば、行いたいことはできます。大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 良かったです。他にも、mattn さんのブログ記事[「golang の channel を使ったテクニックあれこれ」](https://mattn.kaoriya.net/software/lang/go/20160706165757.htm)が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 重ね重ね、ありがとうございます。goroutineはただ並列計算ができると考えていましたが、ワーカーを作成することで用途は広がりそうです。ありがとうございました。